# How to maintain interpolation when keyframing F-curve?

Tags: animation, keyframes, fcurves

Inserting keyframe ruins Bezier interpolation. There is an option **Sample keyframes**, but it inserts keyframe for every frame - this is too much for me. How to do it without additional handwork?

Top to bottom: *original curve, single keyframe inserted, sampled*

[image]

Comment: This sounds like a bug in blender.  To preserve the curve shape the control points must be adjusted according to exact formulas for subdividing a bezier curve.  https://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/Bezier/bezier-sub.html

Comment: Can I ask what you aim to do? I ask because if you want the exact same curve, why do you need to add a keyframe?

Comment: Lemon, because in my real project I have a curve (about 2000 frames) which is already fit in whole animation scene, but now I want to behave it differently from frame 500 to 650 without affecting outside values. Basicaly, I would like to put bounadaries with this keyframes at 500 and 650 frames